# Amazon RDS cost savings suggestion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm looking to reduce my production RDS cost by converting from GP2 to magnetic. Here's an IOPS graph to show how little IOPS my RDS is consuming versus the amount of storage allocated (2TB).

[image: IOPS]

The RDS has an instance type of t2.xlarge with multi-AZ, so you can imagine the amount of workload for this kind of instance. Questions I would like to ask:

1. Is there any real world cases where magnetic storage is used for similar workload like this?
2. Assuming it's fine to use magnetic storage for production RDS, I understand that IOPS will be depleted during conversion. However since I have multi-AZ enabled, will the conversion take place at the standby RDS, before it's promoted to become the new master RDS?